# What's the point of cache coherency?

Tags: multithreading, caching, concurrency, x86, low-level

On CPUs like x86, which provide cache coherency, how is this useful from a practical perspective?  I understand that the idea is to make memory updates done on one core immediately visible on all other cores.  This is a useful property.  However, one can't rely too heavily on it if not writing in assembly language, because the compiler can store variable assignments in registers and never write them to memory.  This means that one must still take explicit steps to make sure that stuff done in other threads is visible in the current thread.  Therefore, from a practical perspective, what has cache coherency achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine you do this:

```
lock(); //some synchronization primitive e.g. a semaphore/mutex
globalint = somevalue;
unlock();
```

If there were no cache coherence, that last `unlock()` would have to assure that `globalint` are now visible everywhere, with cache coherance all you need to do is to write it to memory and let the hardware do the magic. A software solution would have keep tack of which memory exists in which caches, on which cores, and somehow make sure they're atomically in sync.

You'd win an award if you can find a software solution that keeps track of all the pieces of memory that exist in the caches that needs to be keept in sync, that's more efficient than a current hardware solution.

Comment: But in your example, clearly the programmer knows they are writing to a global value, and they could include a flush/synchronization primitive to ensure the write to `globalint` propagates to other cores. Or we could handle this at the library level, by putting the sync. primitive in the `unlock()` method. So I'm not sure this example is a great one to answer the question. You'd have to show why one of the above two approaches wouldn't also work.

Answer (score 10):

The short story is, non-cache coherent system are exceptionally difficult to program  especially if you want to maintain efficiency - which is also the main reason even most NUMA systems today are cache-coherent.

If the caches wern't coherent, the "explicit steps" would have to enforce the coherency - explicit steps are usually things like critical sections/mutexes(e.g. volatile in C/C++ is rarly enough) . It's quite hard, if not impossible for services such as mutexes to keep track of only the memory that have changes and needs to be updated in all the caches -it would probably have to update all the memory, and that is if it could even track which cores have what pieces of that memory in their caches.

Presumable the hardware can do a much better and efficient job at tracking the memory addresses/ranges that have been changed, and keep them in sync.

And, imagine a process running on core 1 and gets preempted. When it gets scheduled again, it got scheduled on core 2.

This would be pretty fatal if the  caches weren't choerent as otherwise there might be remnants of the process data in the cache of core 1, which doesn't exist in core 2's cache. Though, for systems working  that way, the OS would have to enforce the cache coherency as threads are scheduled - which would probably be an "update all the memory in caches between all the cores" operation, or perhaps it could track dirty pages vith the help of the MMU and only sync the memory pages that have been changed - again, the hardware likely keep the caches coherent in a more finegrainded and effcient way.

Comment: Process migration between cores isn't terribly frequent, so the cost of flushing the write cache for any core which loses a process, or flushing the read cache for any core which gains one, really shouldn't be too much of a problem.  A bigger issue is that if process #1 is running on cores A and B, while process #2 is running on C and D, cores C and D shouldn't need to invest any resources watching memory accesses made on behalf of process #1 by cores A and B, since those memory areas really shouldn't be of interest.

Answer (score 9):

There are some nuances not covered by the great responses from the other authors.

First off, consider that a CPU doesn't deal with memory byte-by-byte, but with cache lines.  A line might have 64 bytes.  Now, if I allocate a 2 byte piece of memory at location P, and another CPU allocates an 8 byte piece of memory at location P + 8, and both P and P + 8 live on the same cache line, observe that without cache coherence the two CPUs can't concurrently update P and P + 8 without clobbering each others changes!  Because each CPU does read-modify-write on the cache line, they might both write out a copy of the line that doesn't include the other CPU's changes!  The last writer would win, and one of your modifications to memory would have "disappeared"!

The other thing to bear in mind is the distinction between coherency and consistency.  Because even x86 derived CPUs use store buffers, there aren't the guarantees you might expect that instructions that have already finished have modified memory in such a way that other CPUs can see those modifications, even if the compiler has decided to write the value back to memory (maybe because of `volatile`?).  Instead the mods may be sitting around in store buffers.  Pretty much all CPUs in general use are cache coherent, but very few CPUs have a consistency model that is as forgiving as the x86's.  Check out, for example, http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/classes/573/notes/consistency.html for more information on this topic.

Hope this helps, and BTW, I work at Corensic, a company that's building a concurrency debugger that you may want to check out.  It helps pick up the pieces when assumptions about concurrency, coherence, and consistency prove unfounded :)

Comment: access forbidden to the link. Error 403.(

Answer (score 1):

Cache coherency becomes extremely important when you are dealing with multiple threads and are accessing the same variable from multiple threads. In that particular case, you *have* to ensure that all processors/cores do see the same value if they access the variable at the same time, otherwise you'll have wonderfully non-deterministic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed for locking.  The locking code would include cache flushing if that was needed.  It's mainly needed to ensure that concurrent updates by different processors to different variables in the same cache line aren't lost.

Answer (score 0):

Cache coherency is implemented in hardware because the programmer doesn't have to worry about making sure all threads see the latest value of a memory location while operating in multicore/multiprocessor enviroment. Cache coherence gives an abstraction that all cores/processors are operating on a single unified cache, though every core/processor has it own individual cache.

It also makes sure the legacy multi-threaded code works as is on new processors models/multi processor systems, without making any code changes to ensure data consistency.